# PHP random_int(0,63) : Cannot open source device

Tags: php, nextcloud

This PHP code :

```
<?php
    random_int(0,63);
?>
```

fails with this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Cannot open source device in /usr/htdocs/rand.php:2
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 /usr/htdocs/rand.php(2):
> random_int(0, 2)
>
> #1 {main} thrown in /usr/htdocs/rand.php on line 2

I can't set up my nextcloud server because of this error... What is the problem please ?

Comment: https://secure.php.net/random_int

Answer (score 0):

From https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php:

> The sources of randomness used for this function are as follows:
>
> - On Windows, » CryptGenRandom() will always be used.
> - On Linux, the »    getrandom(2) syscall will be used if available.
> - On other platforms,    /dev/urandom will be used.
> - **If none of the aforementioned sources are    available, then an Exception will be thrown.**

About the algorithms from the list:

- CryptGenRandom is a software based pseudo random algorithm
- getrandom(2) and /dev/urandom draw their randomness from the noise on the physical devices on the machine

In your hosting's case, none if available, so an `Exception` is thrown (I've never seen this before, it might mean your hosting provider is not great).

What you may be able to use instead, and what I would recommend instead of `random_int`, is [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php). It requires the Openssl library to be compiled in, which is a norm.

Note; the aforementioned function returns binary result, which you can easily convert to a hex by using `bin2hex`, or from a hex to int by using `hexdec`.

Examples:

```
$int = hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(1, $strong))); // 1 byte int
$int = hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(2, $strong))); // 2 byte int
```

- Bin2hex: http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php
- Hexdec: http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php